# Stop users from navigating to a page that is restricted to their role

Tags: meteor, roles, iron-router

I want to restrict access to certain pages depending on users roles. So I don't want a logged in user to be able to just change the URL in their browser to navigate to a page they shouldn't have access to. So for such a route I'm doing something like:

```
action: function () {
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin')) {
        this.render("AcressRestricted");
    } else {
        // Do routing for admin users here....
    }
}
```

Is that the standard way to go? And do I need to add this code to every page I want to restrict or is there a more general solution / short cut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Router.onBeforeAction:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin')) {
        this.render("AcressRestricted");
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, {only : 'route_one', 'route_two'});
```

This will only work for `route_one` and `route_two`.

Be sure to name what you use in 'only' or 'except' in your route definitions:

```
Router.route('/' {
    name: 'route_one',
    ...
});
```

Comment: I didn't realise I had to name routes for `except`, this might be the answer to my other question! But otherwise I like this solution, should I have it in the same `Router.onBeforeAction` as my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522609/routing-to-home-screen-when-not-signed-in) or is it ok to make two functions?. Once again, I'll try this out tonight, thanks!

Comment: @Dan Yes its fine to make two functions. You can assign each to whichever set of routes you want. I think your issue was with naming the routes. With the other question too..

Answer (score 1):

You could set your code up a little differently in order to make it more readily reusable, and avoid having to copy and paste any changes across routes:

```
var adminFilter = function () {


if (Meteor.logginIn()) {
   //Logic for if they are an admin
    this.render('loading');
    this.stop();
  } else if (!user.admin()) {
    // Logic for if they are
    this.render('AcressRestricted');
    this.stop();
  }
};
```

And then whenever you need it, just drop it in along side "before:"

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('adminPage', {
    path: '/admin',
    before: adminFilter
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, putting it in a function of course! I'm going to try out Akshat's answer first though as it lets me keep a list of all the "restricted" routes together but thanks for this idea!